# How to make a pyramid alphabet, Java

Tags: java

Im stuck on my assigment on alphabet pyramid.
The pyramid is supposed to look like this using user input:

give a letter: `d`

```
    aa   
   baab  
  cbaabc 
 dcbaabcd
```

but 'my'(i looked help from internet) code's output looks like this:

```
   a   
  aba
 abcba
abcdcba
```

code looks like this:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("give a letter: ");
        char input = key.next().charAt(0);
        
        char middle = 'a'; int spaces = input - (int) 'a';

        while( middle <= input) {
    
            // Print the left side spaces
            for( int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
                System.out.print(" ");
    
            // Print the left side of the tree (including the middle)
            for(char y = 'a'; y <= middle; y++)
                System.out.print(y);
    
            // Print the right side of the tree
            for(char y = Character.toChars(middle - 1)[0]; y >= 'a'; y--)
                System.out.print(y);
    
            // Print the right side spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
                System.out.print(" ");
    
            // Print a new line
            System.out.println();
    
            // Subtract 1 from the number of spaces we need
            spaces--; 
    
            // Increment the middle character
            middle++;
            
        } key.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is wondering the answer i finally figured it out!
here is the code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
       char [] alphabeth= {'0', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'å', 'ä', 'ö'};
       System.out.print("Anna pieni kirjain: ");

       String input = lukija.nextLine();

        char inputChar = input.charAt(0);

        int rows = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < alphabeth.length; i++){
            if(alphabeth[i] == inputChar){
                rows = i;
                break;
            }
        }


       int i , j = 0;
        //top
       for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
       {
        //left side
           for (j = 0; j <= rows - i; j++)
           { if(j != 0)
               System.out.print(" ");
           }
           //middle
           for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
           {
               System.out.print(alphabeth[j]);
           } 
           //right side
           for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
           {
               System.out.print(alphabeth[j]);
           }              
           System.out.println("");
       }
       //Close the resources
       lukija.close();
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).